# JComboBox enabled by another jcomboBox

Tags: java

Can we enable a jcomboBox according to a click on an item of another jcomboBox after the execution of our jFrame? is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, by catching the valueChange event on the first one

Comment: if you can give me some details , or a link who can solve my problem , thank you in advance.

Comment: @jhamon please show me where I can find this `valueChange` event you refer to.

Comment: @bAbra, I  got confused with vaadin, for swing it's ActionEvent

Answer (score 0):

```
JComboBox comboBox_1 = new JComboBox();
comboBox_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try {
            ind = comboBox_1.getSelectedIndex();
            System.out.println(ind);
            if(ind==1) {
                comboBox_4.setEnabled(true);
            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
        }
    });
```